# Clojure: How to Check if Input is Only One Sequence Long?

Tags: recursion, clojure

```
(defn recursive_function

 [total]                   ;let's say total is: (why you(piece of(poop)))

  (cond                    ;if there is only one parenthesis set left

 (;if only (why you) is left) (System/exit 0)

  )

 (map (fn [i]    
     (cond
       (seq? i) (recursive_function total)

       ;otherwise do things to make total shorter (I did not add this code as it
       ;would make this stack overflow question rather long. But essentially this map
       ;will eventually recursively reduce  (why you(piece of(poop))) to ->  (why you)

       )
   idealreturn) 

)
```

Once "total" is reduced to a single sequence or parenthesis such as (why you), how can I write a Cond to check if it is only one parenthesis set?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the question correctly. So if you want to check if the the sequence doesn't contain any sequences as elements.

```clj
(not-any? seq? '(why you))
=> true

(not-any? seq? '(why you (piece of (poop)))
=> false
```